# How to implement quadview in blink id IOS sdk similar like the one in blink id android sdk

Tags: ios, microblink, blinkid

How to implement quadview in blink id IOS sdk similar like the one in blink id android sdk?
I have try to implement it in android version, just IOS sdk is lack of info on this to use the sdk.

Here is the example from android SDK.

[Quadview android blink id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M8Us.png)

Answer (score 2):

While there is a way to add a rectangle by using [LegacyDocumentVerificationOverlay](https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-ios/blob/dc1fa0df5ddd2bac21f313cc0253243a2b58f429/BlinkID.xcframework/ios-arm64/BlinkID.framework/Headers/MBLegacyDocumentVerificationOverlaySettings.h#L4), we've deprecated it and don't recommend using it. It's best practice to use the MBBlinkIdOverlay with the new MBBlinkIdSingleSideRecognizer and MBBlinkIdMultiSideRecognizer since it provides a better UX, more features, and live feedback messages for the users. We kindly suggest referring to the [documentation](https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-ios#-built-in-overlay-view-controllers-and-overlay-subviews) to learn more about the MBBlinkIdOverlay.

Comment: ok, is it possible for me to create the rectangle using MBBlinkIdOverlay?